# changing images on button click

Tags: android, image

I have 3 images in my app. The images are numbers. The maximum number displayed on all the 3 images will be 9. At first the image in the unit's place will be 1 and the rest images will be 0. On Clicking on the "next" button, the next number is being displayed i.e. 2. Proceeding in this way till the last number 9,then on the next click the unit's place becomes 0 and the ten's place becomes 1 and so on will proceed till 999. There is a previous button too which will reverse the condition of next button and will decrement the numbers by one digit. I am able to achieve the next button condition by using if else conditions but unable to do the same for previous button. please help.

```
int image1 = 2;
int image10 = 0;
int image100 = 0;
int max = 10;

final int [] images = {
            R.drawable.num00,R.drawable.num_0, R.drawable.num1, R.drawable.num2, R.drawable.num3, R.drawable.num4,
            R.drawable.num5, R.drawable.num6, R.drawable.num7, R.drawable.num8, R.drawable.num9
    };

    ImageButton next = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if((image1==max)&&(image10<max))                //for value with 9, 19... to increment
            {
                   image1=1;
                   if (image10==0)
                   { 
                       image10=2;                      
                   }
                   else 
                   {
                       image10++;
                   }

                   img1.setImageResource(images[image1]);
                   img2.setImageResource(images[image10]);
            }


            else if((image1==max)&&(image10==max)&&(image100>=0)&&(image100<=10))               //for value with 9 in 1st block to increment
            {
                   image1=1;
                   image10=1;
                   if (image100==0)
                   { 
                       image100=2;                     
                   }
                   else 
                   {
                       image100++;
                   }

                   img1.setImageResource(images[image1]);
                   img2.setImageResource(images[image10]);
                   img3.setImageResource(images[image100]);
            }
            else if (image100<=10)                      //for value below 9 in 1st block to increment
            {
                image1++;
                img1.setImageResource(images[image1]);
            }
}
    });
```

Here, image1 is the position of image in the unit's place, image10 in the ten's place and image100 in the hundred's place.

Comment: Please show your previous button code attempt

Comment: Do You always start from 0 when app is started? Just an idea: one counter `number = 0;` on clik You either incremet or decrement counter, and You set images with something like `img1.setImageResource(images[number%10]);` `img2.setImageResource(images[(number/10)%10]);` `img3.setImageResource(images[number/100]);`

Comment: If you find my answer as correct, Accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation can be optimized a lot.

Why cant you go for a simple number like below.

int number = 0;

for next button:

```
if(number <1000){
number++
updateImages()
}
```

for previous button:

```
if(number > 0){
number--
updateImages()
}
```

After doing the above line for those prev/next buttons, simply write a method like below.

```
updateImages(){
unitsPlace = number%10;
tensPlace = ((number/10)%10);
hundredsPlace = ((number/100)%10);
img1.setImageResource(images[hundredsPlace]);
img2.setImageResource(images[tensPlace]);
img3.setImageResource(images[unitsPlace]);
}
```

Thats it.